# Is EntityFramework available for Windows 8 Store Apps?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5, windows-store-apps, .net-4.5

Is EntityFramework available for Windows 8 Store Apps?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows 8. 
I'm starting to wonder because I can't make it work.

I installed the Entity Framework package from NuGet
I added System.Data.Entity and System.Data.Design to the project

But no matter what I do, DbContext isn't recognized...

Any ideas?

EDIT:

EntityFramework isn't available for Windows Store Apps. I don't understand Microsoft position on this, they suck.

The other solution is to use SQLite but it's not ORM. So what's the point?

Comment: EntityFramework is not available for Windows 8 Store Apps. You can use SQLite : http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx

Comment: SQLite isn't ORM, is it?

Comment: @AntoineGamond no it is not, but i think there are some OS projects that can help with that.

Comment: @JordyvanEijk what OS projects ? :) Thanks for the quick reply btw

Comment: @HenkHolterman what do you mean by client; I guess you are not referencing client applications like silverlight; but asp.net etc. But the problem is in order to work with an ORM tool, you need a database in the end. W8 employs web services etc for receiving data, like silverlight there is no way to access DB directly.

Comment: You can create WCF SOAP/RESTful service with entity framework and consume it in Windows Store App. I have used in my app.

Comment: I think it's an awful approach, especially if I need offline access to my app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, Windows 8 Store Apps target WinRT (Windows Runtime).

For that reason, because WinRT can be targeted using C# and there're a lot of classes from .NET Framework having a match in WinRT, most of available code base not using very specific libraries may work also on Windows 8 Store Apps.

There're a lot of things unavailable in WinRT. For example, Entity Framework is built on top of ADO.NET and this isn't available on WinRT.

Visual Studio is *smart enough* to hide such classes and components that aren't available on WinRT and this is why Entity Framework related classes can't be used in your Windows 8 Store App project.

In order to use Entity Framework, you'll need to create a RESTful Web API (for example using ASP.NET Web API) and access the data layer asynchronously over the wire.

Otherwise, you'll need to use a local database storage like SQLite or XML.

Comment: In other terms, Microsoft sucks. The App needs to work in offline mode. I think it's the case for most apps. And SQLite isn't ORM...

Comment: @AntonieGamond In my humild opinion, Microsoft has downgraded Windows 8 app development as if it was mobile development. I mean that a tablet or laptop, or even a desktop PC, don't have the limitations of mobile development. Or you can argue that Microsoft wants every device to be connected to internet and force everyone to use the cloud (i.e. Azure). Is a good reason, isn't it? ;)

Comment: @AntoineGamond I'm not sure about this, but you can give a try to *Dapper*, the mini-OR/M behind StackExchange. Maybe it fits your needs (or who knows).

Comment: @AntoineGamond I don't know if *Dapper* can work on Windows 8 / WinRT.

Comment: Persisting data in an easy way is just a basic thing. Everyone needs it. Not doing it is just bad.. Mobile dev or not.

Comment: @AntoineGamond Note that my thoughts are full of irony. I'll vote for the reason of "move everyone to the cloud". Microsoft, Google and any software giant is looking to do more asynchronous work on the net and do the less in the device. Maybe because these devices work unplugged and using batteries and offloading them increases battery life, but there're some other cases like yours that may be covered in any development environment. Also in Windows 8 Store Apps!

Comment: @Antoine Gamond you can use [Mobile App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/app-service/mobile/) formerly known as `Mobile Services`. it has an offline sync mode that works pretty well for most scenarios

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework is not available for Windows 8 store apps. This is due to the fact that windows store apps run in a sandbox and will not be able to use normal database. You can use SQLite for this or have XML / JSon as source which you can deploy in IsolatedStorage of the app on first start of the app.

Comment: _run in sandbox_ does not seem to be a full explanation... What part of EF would be unsafe?

Comment: On iOS, apps are also sandboxed, but that doesn't mean, we can't have a database in the sandbox. I don't understand what is the official Microsoft approach for this? They build a great framework but it's not compatible with Windows 8 apps?

Comment: Maybe a good argument is that the most part of a Windows Store App works on top of Windows RT instead of regular Win32/.NET, meaning that a lot of code base won't work on Windows 8 Modern UI apps.

Answer (score 2):

No it's not available. You may use SQLite, this [HowTo](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx) was very helpful for me. Works great!

Comment: SQLite isn't ORM. We're in 2013... Do you know LinqConnect ? http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/

Answer (score 1):

For the record:
The answer is not and the turnaround is to create a web service or use a cloud service.  SqlLite is fine for store local (single user) information but nothing more.

About this matter, not all, but most connections to the database are done via a socket connection. So its possible to connect to some database and still keeping the application in a sandbox.
However, the intentions of MS is clear : cloud or bust.   So MS is saying that its best to connect to a web service (another a socket connection) that its inefficient (and risky) rather to use a direct connection.

Windows Store Apps is simply inferior.

And for adding insult over injury, MS wants to cut some earning from our software.

I really tried to like WinRT (now UWP) but its impossible.   And during this 3 years, things aren't changed a bit.